# debugging missing reference to figure

Tags: graphics, floats, cross-referencing

to put it plainly: is there a way to debug the way a `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}` block is processed? I got all my figures in my paper, their  references are alright except for 2 of them (incidentally the last 2 in the document) even though they're declared in exactly the same way like any other picture in the paper. Reference to them don't go into the .aux file but I don't see errors that can help understand.

the following is the way pictures are included

```
% this picture number shows up correctly wherever referenced

\begin{figure}
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{denCont.eps}
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{denCont_irr.eps}
\caption{AFM image ...}
\label{fig:DEN}
\end{figure}

% these 2 are placed in the page as expected but references don't appear

\begin{figure}
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{RplotNONDEN.eps}
\caption{Boxplot of ...}
\label{fig:BoxND}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{RplotDEN_EN.eps}
\caption{Boxplot of ...}
\label{fig:BoxDEN}       
\end{figure}
```

the only clue in the console output is in this trace of the `\@writefile` command but doesn't hint at any explicit error

```
[7
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {5}{\ignorespaces Boxplot of ...}}{7}{figure.5}}
\newlabel{fig:BoxND}{{5}{7}{Boxplot of ...}{figure.5}{}}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {6}{\ignorespaces Boxplot of...}}{7}{figure.6}}
\newlabel{fig:BoxDEN}{{6}{7}{Boxplot of ...}{figure.6}{}}
]
```

Comment: Well, you could post an example of a random figure in your document, and then the last two, so we can compare. The content is not important, but post all the tags, etc...

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE by the way!

Comment: Well, your code works as expected for me. Have you tried deleting the auxiliary files and recompiling?

Comment: yes, I did. I insist there must be a reason for the console output I showed before. It's not printed for any other figure except for the 2 with missing references. Still there is no error message associated to it, hence my question about a mechanism for deeper debugging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that the writefile appears on the terminal means that the information got written to the aux file *after* the aux file was closed for writing.

99 times out of a hundred when that is seen it is because `\include` has been redefined not to use `\clearpage`, in which case the solution is to remove that redefinition.

Comment: Thanks! that's a step ahead toward a solution, but there is no obvious point where this redefinition could have taken place. The code posted is a quite accurate excerpt, only a plain text paragraph between the first and second figure blocks was removed, no Latex commands  were purged for brevity (exception a few \ref or \cite commands in the text paragraph)

Comment: @MassimoManghi What about the preamble: any particular options?

Comment: hold on, David, you are correct. I initially misinterpreted your suggestion. I expected the redefinition to be between the figure inclusion, but I found out the main .tex file redefined \clearpage to avoid page break between \section blocks. It works now after I removed a \let\clearpage\relax command, still it's weird because it was in the main file and placed before all the \include sequence of 6 paper sections but struck only on the last one. I have now to understand how to properly avoid page breaks between \section blocks

Comment: @Alenanno thank you for your help and glad to be a member of Tex SE!

Comment: @MassimoManghi You're welcome. Consider accepting David's answer if it solved your problem (the √ sign next to the answer).

Comment: @MassimoManghi if you are using `\include` you can not avoid the page break (use `\input` instead)

Comment: Yes, I found out about \include implying a page break. Quite evidently the \clearpage\relax was an ugly kludge to avoid it in a quick and dirty way. Now figures and reference work perfectly, thanks